# Creating a dynamic link without creating a new .php page/file

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, hyperlink

I'm new to PHP and I'm looking for possible way(s) to create a dynamic link without creating a new .php page/file

So, I'm coding a blog, which the posts are categorized. Category A, B, C and so on.

And my table

```
id int(11)
title varchar(255)
post_category varchar(50)
post_content text
num_comments int(11)
date_posted date
```

This is how the post's category set

```
foreach ($category as $cat=>$value) {
    $post_category = "";
    $post_category .= $value." ";
}
```

with a checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="CategoryA"> CategoryA 
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="CategoryB"> CategoryB
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="CategoryC"> CategoryC
```

In the index.php, I need to know how to create dynamic links like Category A, Category B, and so on..

And those link contain the posts according to their category(ies) without creating a file CategoryA.php CategoryB.php and so on

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a php file called category.php. and then pass in which category you are interested in with a get variable.  so for instance category.php?cat=A  would get you category A.  You can read this variable like this `echo $_GET["cat"]`  If you want more information look here:  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

In your sql you will want to select your category something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table_name` WHERE `post_category` like '%'".$cat."'%'
```

Depending on your version of PHP you should use mysql_real_escape_string() around any input that is used as a mysql query. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Your example is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Like this, man?

    echo '<a href="/dev/category.php?cat'.$_GET['cat'].'">CategoryX</a>;

Comment: More like `<a href="/dev/category.php?cat=a">CategoryA</a><a href="/dev/category.php?cat=b">CategoryX</b>`  Then do the $_GET code in the category.php file

Answer (score 0):

On you blog page create a link with a :

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($posts)) {
     // your code to display your content here
     // this ill create a link with a GET request and is passed with the post ID
     echo '<a href="category.php?id='.$row['category']'"><button class="read-more">Read More
     </button>  </a>'; 
 }
```

On your category page:

```
// get post category from GET
$cat = $_GET['category'];
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) or die('Error connecting to server');
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category = '$cat'";
$posts = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($posts)) {
    // your code to display your single post content here                   
}
```

Downside is that you don't have permalinks to your content. it will always look like this
category.php?id=SomeRandomNumber. But there will probably be a way to fix that.